# Determine the clicked model?

Tags: marionette

Currently I'm inserting id attrbute in the template to get the model clicked by the user.

```
    ArticlesView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    childView: ArticleView,

    ui: {
        "add": ".btnAdd",
    },
    events: {
        "click @ui.add" : "addToSelection",
    },
    addToSelection: function(event){
        //Get the current item's id.
        var clicked = $(event.currentTarget);
        var article = articles.get(clicked.attr("id"));
        selecteds.add([article.clone()]);
    },
});
```

My Question is: There is any other way to get the clicked Model without using the id attribute in the template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is! Each of your `childView`s should have a `model` property: you should thus add your per-model methods in the view class definition, here `ArticleView`.

That could look something like this:

```
var ArticlesView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    childView: ArticleView
});


var ArticleView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    ui: {
        "add": ".btnAdd",
    },
    events: {
        "click @ui.add" : "addToSelection",
    },
    addToSelection: function(){
        selecteds.add(this.model); 
    }
});
```